# Expressing a $3\times 3$ determinant as the product of four factors

Tags: matrices, determinant, factoring

I am attempting to express the determinant below as a product of four linear factors
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & bc & b+c\\
b & ca & c+a\\
c & ab & a+b\\
\end{vmatrix}
= 
a\begin{vmatrix}
ca & c+a\\
ab & a+b\\
\end{vmatrix}
-
bc\begin{vmatrix}
b & c+a\\
c & a+b\\
\end{vmatrix}
+(b+c)\begin{vmatrix}
b & ca\\
c & ab\\
\end{vmatrix}$$
This is as far as I get before it gets too messy
$$
=a^3(c-b)-bc\{(b-c)(b+c)+a(b-c)\}+a(b-c)(b+c)^2
$$
But I cant seem to arrive at the answer in the book, which is given as 
$$
(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c)
$$

Am I doing something wrong as I have been stuck on this question for three days.

Thanks in advance!
$$
$$

Comment: Alternatively, subtract row 1 from row 2, and factor out $a-b$ from row 2; subtract row 1 from row 3, and factor out $a-c$ from row 3; subtract row 2 from row 3, and factor out $b-c$ from row 3; see what's left.

Comment: My excuses Gerry, I turned the comment into a reply & left yours hanging :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding the 1st to the 3rd column to create a column of $a+b+c$'s. Then subtract 3rd row from 2nd & 1st ones to make two out of three entries in that column zero. Now expand wrt that column.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Add first column to third column & take (a+b+c) out from third column.
2. Now Subtract Row2 from Row1 & take a-b out from Row1
3. Subtract Row3 from Row2 & take b-c out from Row2.
4. Now Multiply -1 to Row1 & Add Row1 & Row2.
5. Now take c-a out from Row1.
6. Now calculate determinant as usual.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & bc & b+c\\
b & ca & c+a\\
c & ab & a+b
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
a & bc & b+c\\
b  -a & c(a-b)& a-b\\
c -a& b(a-c)& a-c
\end{vmatrix}=(a-b)(c-a)
\begin{vmatrix}
a & bc & b+c\\
-1&c&1\\
1&-b&-1
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$=(a-b)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
a& bc& b+c\\
-1&c&-1\\
0&b-c&0
\end{vmatrix}
=(a-b)(c-a)(b-c)(a+b+c)$$